# How to join two dataframes with different column sets in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have two pandas dataframes: df1 and df2.

```
data_df1 = {
    'seller': ['John', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Alice'],
    'date': ['2023-07-25', '2023-07-26', '2023-07-27', '2023-07-28']
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_df1)

data_df2 = {
    'seller': ['Alice Perry', 'John Russell', 'Bob Foster', 'Alice Mcgee'],
    'id': [101, 102, 103, 104],
    'date': ['2023-07-26', '2023-07-25', '2023-07-27', '2023-07-26']
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_df2)
```

I want to perform a join between these dataframes based on the 'seller' and 'date' columns. It is worth mentioning that the seller column is not the same in both dataframes, one has only the name (df1) and the other has the full name (df2) and the date is not the same, so the merge must be by proximity, not exact dates.

How can I perform the join and get the desired result? Should I convert the 'date' columns to a common format before joining, and if so, how can I do that?

I appreciate any insights or examples on how to accomplish this join correctly. Thank you!

I already managed to make the conversion of dates for the join to work, but I don't know how to do this with the names

Comment: you must perform the _merge_ logic and transform the data yourself. For example, `data_df2['merge_date']=pd.to_datetime(data_df2['date']).normalize()`, same for `data_df1` and merge on `merge_date`.

Comment: I would suggest you to use str.split function for "seller" column

Answer (score 1):

Standardize the `date` columns:

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date']).dt.date
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date']).dt.date
```

Extract only the first name for `df2`:

```
df2['first_name'] = df2['seller'].str.split(' ').str[0]
```

Merge using `.merge()`:

```
result_df = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', left_on=['seller', 'date'], right_on=['first_name', 'date'])
```

Output:

> ```
>   seller_x        date      seller_y   id first_name
> 0     John  2023-07-25  John Russell  102       John
> 1    Alice  2023-07-26   Alice Perry  101      Alice
> 2    Alice  2023-07-26   Alice Mcgee  104      Alice
> 3      Bob  2023-07-27    Bob Foster  103        Bob
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])

df1.merge(df2, left_on=['seller', 'date'],
          right_on=[df2['seller'].str.extract(r'(\w+)', expand=False), df2['date'].dt.normalize()],
          suffixes=(None, '_'))
```

Output:

```
 seller       date       seller_   id               date_
0   John 2023-07-25  John Russell  102 2023-07-25 11:45:00
1  Alice 2023-07-26   Alice Perry  101 2023-07-26 12:30:00
2  Alice 2023-07-26   Alice Mcgee  104 2023-07-26 16:20:00
3    Bob 2023-07-27    Bob Foster  103 2023-07-27 08:15:00
```

If you only want to keep one of the keys:

```
out = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['seller', 'date'],
                right_on=[df2['seller'].str.extract(r'(\w+)', expand=False),
                          df2['date'].dt.normalize()],
               suffixes=(None, '_')
               ).drop(columns=['seller_', 'date_'])
```

Output:

```
  seller       date   id
0   John 2023-07-25  102
1  Alice 2023-07-26  101
2  Alice 2023-07-26  104
3    Bob 2023-07-27  103
```

Answer (score 0):

Good Day,

There are few things to consider in your example.

1. Joins on the dates needs to be the same data type, so make them both dates instead of datetimes.  df["date"] = df["date"].astype(date)
2. Join in the seller might be a bit more complicated.  In df1 you have only the first name, but in df2 you have the full name.  You can separate them into seller_first and seller_last using something like: df2["seller_first"] = df2["seller"].partition(" ")[0], but the real problem is in your data.  You have two entries in df1 with Alice and two entries in df2 that begin with Alice.  Your join will not know how to resolve this correctly since the Alice in df2 are different people.